# How do I add a second point variable on animated maps R?

Tags: r, animation, maps

I am new to animating data in R. I am trying to animate 2 variables (NO2 levels and Vehicles numbers) with hourly readings between lockdown and Prelockdown on one map, so that it shows the change in both variables by location (for 3 sensors) by day and hour for April 2019 and April 2020. I can do one variable (shown in the code) and even have the point change shape to represent rush hour traffic) but am having trouble getting the second variable (vehicles) to work. The idea is to show how having less traffic in lockdown reduces NO2 levels (although the regression for this is less than would be expected).

I know the data for lockdown will be 2 days apart from last year (leap year) but this is just for teaching purposes at present so I am not attempting to download more data to try and fix that yet. What I would like to know is how do I get the vehicles data to display at the same time as the NO2 data? I have tried adding another `geom_point` and nudging it over slightly so they don't overlap but it didn't work - I don't think I can have 2 geom_points on one map. I am now trying geom_jitter for the vehicles and can get it changing colour but not changing size. It seems that you can only have one scale_size per map. Is there a way around this?

Edited to use `dput` to add the data and show another example of what I have tried - hope I have this correct now.
Edited again to try and be clearer and put code for the single variable that works

```r
structure(list(Location = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L), .Label = c("Coast_Road", "Gosforth", "TyneBridge"), class = "factor"), 
    Date = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("1/4/2019", 
    "1/4/2020", "10/4/2019", "10/4/2020", "11/4/2019", "11/4/2020", 
    "12/4/2019", "12/4/2020", "13/4/2019", "13/4/2020", "14/4/2019", 
    "14/4/2020", "15/4/2019", "15/4/2020", "16/4/2019", "16/4/2020", 
    "17/4/2019", "17/4/2020", "18/4/2019", "18/4/2020", "19/4/2019", 
    "19/4/2020", "2/4/2019", "2/4/2020", "20/4/2019", "20/4/2020", 
    "21/4/2019", "21/4/2020", "22/4/2019", "22/4/2020", "23/4/2019", 
    "23/4/2020", "24/4/2019", "24/4/2020", "25/4/2019", "25/4/2020", 
    "26/4/2019", "26/4/2020", "27/4/2019", "27/4/2020", "28/4/2019", 
    "28/4/2020", "29/4/2019", "29/4/2020", "3/4/2019", "3/4/2020", 
    "30/4/2019", "30/4/2020", "4/4/2019", "4/4/2020", "5/4/2019", 
    "5/4/2020", "6/4/2019", "6/4/2020", "7/4/2019", "7/4/2020", 
    "8/4/2019", "8/4/2020", "9/4/2019", "9/4/2020"), class = "factor"), 
    Date2 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), Hour = c("04", 
    "03", "02", "01", "04", "03", "01", "02", "04", "01", "02", 
    "03", "04", "03", "02", "01", "03", "04", "02", "04", "01", 
    "03", "02", "01"), Day = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 7L, 
    7L, 7L, 7L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 7L, 
    2L, 7L, 7L, 7L), .Label = c("Fri", "Mon", "Sat", "Sun", "Thurs", 
    "Tues", "wed"), class = "factor"), Lock = structure(c(2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Lockdown", "PreLockdown"
    ), class = "factor"), Rush = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("NonRushHour", "RushHour"
    ), class = "factor"), NO2 = c(27.76196, 35.78016, 45.7216, 
    22.2686, 6.23032, 5.7622, 8.53896, 11.8158, 22.16896, 28.5572, 
    24.957, 18.73608, 4.60976, 4.11532, 10.5656, 5.6024, 25.98724, 
    28.00448, 50.7224, 8.65552, 82.8046, 11.8722, 8.4506, 9.3812
    ), Vehicles = c(38L, 54L, 43L, 37L, 20L, 34L, 30L, 41L, 14L, 
    13L, 6L, 10L, 23L, 19L, 18L, 16L, 31L, 43L, 30L, 49L, 35L, 
    30L, 38L, 26L), DateTime = c(1.04, 1.03, 1.02, 1.01, 1.04, 
    1.03, 1.01, 1.02, 1.04, 1.01, 1.02, 1.03, 1.04, 1.03, 1.02, 
    1.01, 1.03, 1.04, 1.02, 1.04, 1.01, 1.03, 1.02, 1.01), Lon = c(-1.5662, 
    -1.5662, -1.5662, -1.5662, -1.5662, -1.5662, -1.5662, -1.5662, 
    -1.6199, -1.6199, -1.6199, -1.6199, -1.6199, -1.6199, -1.6199, 
    -1.6199, -1.606, -1.606, -1.606, -1.606, -1.606, -1.606, 
    -1.606, -1.606), Lat = c(54.9944, 54.9944, 54.9944, 54.9944, 
    54.9944, 54.9944, 54.9944, 54.9944, 55.0071, 55.0071, 55.0071, 
    55.0071, 55.0071, 55.0071, 55.0071, 55.0071, 54.968, 54.968, 
    54.968, 54.968, 54.968, 54.968, 54.968, 54.968)), row.names = c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 5L, 1074L, 1080L, 1331L, 1430L, 1481L, 1501L, 1502L, 
1605L, 2198L, 2202L, 2204L, 2205L, 2966L, 2968L, 2972L, 3315L, 
3340L, 3441L, 3442L, 3443L), class = "data.frame")
```

Code block:

```r
library(gganimate) library(OpenStreetMap) library(ggplot2) library(maps)

#set lat and long for the size of the map (top left and bottom right coordinates)
 
LAT1 =  54.962130 ; LAT2 = 55.018427 LON1 = -1.556871 ; LON2 =
-1.652677
 
map <- openmap(c(LAT2,LON1), c(LAT1,LON2), zoom = NULL)

map.latlon <- openproj(map) 

My_Theme = theme(   plot.title = element_text(size = 30),  
legend.position = "right",    legend.text = element_text(color =
"black", size = 18),   legend.title = element_text(size = 20),  
axis.title = element_text(size = 25),   axis.text = element_text(size = 20),   strip.text = element_text(face="bold", size=25,lineheight=5.0),   strip.background =
element_rect(fill="lightblue", colour="black", size=1))

OSMap <-  OpenStreetMap::autoplot.OpenStreetMap(map.latlon)+ 
  geom_label(data=pol5, aes(x=Lon ,y=Lat, label=Location, fontface=7), hjust=1.3, vjust=0, size=7) +
  geom_point(aes(x = Lon, y = Lat, size = NO2,  shape = Rush),
             data = pol5, color="red") + 
  
  scale_size_continuous(range = c(4, 30), breaks = c(0, 50, 100, 150, 200)) +
  labs(size = 'NO2')  +
  facet_wrap(~Lock) + 
  My_Theme +   
  labs(title = "Date and Time  {closest_state}") +
  transition_states(DateTime, transition_length = 3, state_length = 1)

animate(OSMap , nframes = 100, fps=12, width = 1600, height = 1000, start_pause= 20, end_pause = 30, rewind = TRUE)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO!  You're right that you can't attach a file, but you can post a copy-and-paste-ready snippet with `dput(pol2)` (ideally, only as much of `pol2` as necessary to demonstrate the problem).  That, plus the sample code you already have, will help you get an answer as quickly as possible.

Comment: ah thank you - that is useful to know. So my data is

Comment: oops apologies for previous comment - newbie error. Thank you for the help - I have edited my post now (hopefully correctly) and would appreciate any help offered.

Comment: The data looks great - loads perfectly on my end.  I'm getting some errors with the rest of the code, though; can you run it by itself on your end and see what needs to be adjusted?  They're likely to be typos, but I can't reconstruct all of the necessary fixes.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have re-run his code and it seems that it needs the bit after scale_color_manual (+latb(title= on a new line, but I get the following error message Error in continuous_scale(aesthetics, "gradient", seq_gradient_pal(low,  : 
  unused arguments (colour = "blue", alpha = 1)
In addition: Warning message:
Ignoring unknown aesthetics: cumulative    - the code does run, but the resulting map has the incorrect legend showing the blue dots as NO2 values not Vehicles. I am not sure if this is because I have set the legends incorrectly, or I am mis-understanding  jitter.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I edited your question in an attempt to make it easier to read. I also think the question lacks focus and should be trimmed down to a [*"Minimal, Reproducible, Example."*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @Ali, did you have an earlier version of the code that didn't produce that error?  Can you edit your question to show the minimal code that shows just the one variable?

Comment: Hi A.S.K I hank you - I have now edited it to include the working code only (I assume it will compile but unfortunately my new laptop is syncing to onedrive and won't compile - something to sort out during the Christmas break) . Hopefully it all makes more sense now (good job I am better at explaining things to students).

Answer (score 0):

One way to get both points on the map is to pivot the dataframe: get one row per "measure", where the "measure" is either NO2 or number of vehicles.  Here's a map with NO2 in red and vehicles in blue; vehicles are moved east a bit so that the points don't overlap.

```
OSMap <-  OpenStreetMap::autoplot.OpenStreetMap(map.latlon) + 
  geom_label(data = pol5,
             aes(x = Lon, y = Lat, label = Location),
             fontface = 7, hjust = 1.3, vjust = 0, size = 7) +
  geom_point(data = pol5 %>%
               dplyr::select(DateTime, Lon, Lat, NO2, Vehicles, Rush, Lock) %>%
               pivot_longer(cols = c("NO2", "Vehicles"), names_to = "measure") %>%
               mutate(Lon = Lon + ifelse(measure == "Vehicles", 0.005, 0)),
             aes(x = Lon, y = Lat, color = measure, fill = measure,
                 size = value, shape = Rush)) +
  scale_size_continuous(range = c(4, 30), breaks = c(0, 50, 100, 150, 200),
                        guide = F) +
  labs(size = 'NO2 or Vehicles')  +
  facet_wrap(~ Lock) + 
  My_Theme +   
  labs(title = "Date and Time  {closest_state}") +
  transition_states(DateTime, transition_length = 3, state_length = 1)
```

[image]

You'll probably need more tinkering to get the exact behavior you want.  For example, as you already noted, it doesn't make sense to have the same scale for NO2 and vehicles; they don't even use the same units.  It works out ok for now because the values of the two measures happen to occupy a similar range, but that wouldn't necessarily be true if you wanted to add some other measure.  I would probably hack things by normalizing the values within each measure to fall in the range [0, 1], where 0 represents the smallest observed value and 1 the largest.  I'm not sure whether it would be possible to show a custom legend with two different size scales; I know these things are not easy in `ggplot2`, by design.  If not, I might suppress the size scale entirely and add labels to the points; here's a rough version of what that might look like:

```
OSMap <-  OpenStreetMap::autoplot.OpenStreetMap(map.latlon) + 
  geom_label(data = pol5,
             aes(x = Lon, y = Lat, label = Location),
             fontface = 7, hjust = 1.3, vjust = 0, size = 7) +
  geom_point(data = pol5 %>%
               dplyr::select(DateTime, Lon, Lat, NO2, Vehicles, Rush, Lock) %>%
               pivot_longer(cols = c("NO2", "Vehicles"), names_to = "measure") %>%
               mutate(Lon = Lon + ifelse(measure == "Vehicles", 0.005, 0)),
             aes(x = Lon, y = Lat, color = measure, fill = measure,
                 size = value, shape = Rush)) +
  geom_text(data = pol5 %>%
              dplyr::select(DateTime, Lon, Lat, NO2, Vehicles, Rush, Lock) %>%
              pivot_longer(cols = c("NO2", "Vehicles"), names_to = "measure") %>%
              mutate(Lon = Lon + ifelse(measure == "Vehicles", 0.005, 0),
                     value = round(value)),
            aes(x = Lon, y = Lat, label = value)) +
  scale_size_continuous(range = c(4, 30), breaks = c(0, 50, 100, 150, 200),
                        guide = F) +
  facet_wrap(~ Lock) + 
  My_Theme +   
  labs(title = "Date and Time  {closest_state}") +
  transition_states(DateTime, transition_length = 3, state_length = 1)
```

[image]